# Ag-Grid filter across pages or current page

Tags: usability, data-tables, grid, pagination, sort

When using the [Ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) with multiple pages, is it a good practice to filter records across pages or should it be just the current page ?
Also for sorting, is it a good practice to retain the current page OR should the user be thrown back to the first page always on sorting ?

Note: I am referring to AgGrid here, but even a generic answers on data grid best practices is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering records in a data grid with multiple pages, it is a common practice to offer the option to filter either the current page or all pages. This allows the user to choose the level of specificity they need for their filtering criteria.

As for sorting, again, it depends on the specific use case and user experience desired. If retaining the current page after sorting helps maintain context and reduces the need for the user to navigate back to their previous location, it can be a good practice. However, if throwing the user back to the first page on sorting helps provide a clear and consistent experience, then it may also be appropriate. The choice ultimately depends on the goals and priorities of the application and its users.

Comment: Thanks...While I understand it depends on the application context, for filtering, as a general/best practice, is filtering across pages a more reliable way ?

Comment: As per the user's point of view, they applied the filters, and they should be expected to apply them across all the pages as well. For reference, you can check with the top e-commerce websites such as Amazon; once you select any particular product across all the pages, the product which is tagged to the filter applied will be displayed.